# How to dynamically add AutoPostBack = true to button in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code. My question is how can I dynamically add the autopostback property to the button?

```
Button button = new Button();
button.ID = "Button" + i;
button.Text = "Save";
button.Click += SaveButton_Click;
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
```

Something like this `button.autoPostBack = true;`

Comment: By default `button` has `AutoPoskBack` property equal to `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default an asp.net `button` control has `AutoPostBack` property equal to `true`. Though this property doesn't appear in `button` properties. If a `Click` event attached to a `button`, it will always do a `server-trip`.

As a side note! if you want that you `button` don't do a `server-trip` then you can disable its `AutoPostBack` property by removing its `Click` event and you could add `OnClientClick` event to run `client-side` code

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="myJSfunction(); return false" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attributes.Add in button.
i.e.

```
button.Attributes.Add("AutoPostback","true");
```

Comment: This is the answer I was thinking of but I believe that it is by default would be the correct answer.